# Writing queries using Doctrine methods?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm having some problems writing some complex queries using Doctrine methods and i would love to know how to do it, maybe someone can help me.

```
1) What's the equivalent of SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = 'admin' and password = 123456
2) What's the equivalent of SELECT name, title FROM products WHERE category_id = 4 AND title LIKE %something%
3) What's the equivalent of SELECT products.id, users.id FROM users INNER JOIN orders ON users.id = orders.buyer INNER JOIN products ON orders.product = products.id WHERE users.id = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
UsersTable::getInstance()->findByUserAndPassword('admin', 123456);
```

2)

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('p.name, p.title')
     ->from('Products p')
     ->where('category_id = ? AND title LIKE ?', array(4, '%something%'));
```

3)

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->select('p.id, u.id')
     ->from('Users u')
     ->innerJoin('u.Order o')
     ->innerJoin('o.Products p')
     ->where('u.id = ?', 2);
```

Real names of Order and Products relations for Users model can be different (depending on the actual schema).

Comment: Do i need to use Doctrine_Query for the other 2? Can't i use methods?

Comment: Also, what does Doctrine_Query returns? An object that i can call fetch, or fetchAll, for example?

Comment: You can use methods to create query like UsersTable::getInstance()->createQuery('u') instead of Doctrine_Query::create(), but then you dont need to specify the from clause.

Comment: Doctrine_Query returns Doctrine_Query object with initialized query params, and you can call execute(), fetchOne() etc on this object to retrieve data from DB.

Comment: GetInstance is equal to Doctrine_Core::getTable('Phonenumber'); ?

Comment: Yes, it is, but by calling through ModelTable::getInstance() you wont have problems with proper model name. You can make a mistake while typing model name like Doctrine_Core::getTable('Phonenumber') and then get errors.